# Python can't read a temporary file

Tags: python, subprocess, output

I have a python program, which is supposed to calculate changes based on a value written in a temporary file (eg. "12345\n"). It is always an integer.

I have tried different methods to read the file, but python wasn't able to read it. So then I had the idea to execute a shell command ("cat") that will return content. When I execute this in the shell it works fine, but python the feedback I get is empty. Then I tried writing a bash and then a php skript, which would read the file and then return the value. In python I called them over the shell and the feedback I get is empty as well.

I was wondering if that was a general problem in python and made my scripts return the content of other temporary files, which worked fine.
Inside my scripts I was able to do calculations with the value and in the shell the output is exactly as expected, but not when called via python. I also noticed that I don't get the value with my extra scripts when they are called by phython (I tried to write it into another file; it was updated but empty).

The file I am trying to read is in the /tmp directory and is written into serveral time per second by another script.
I am looking for a solution (open for new ideas) in which I end up having the value of the file in a python variable.

Thanks for the help

Here are my programs:

python:

```
# python script
import subprocess

stdout = subprocess.Popen(["php /path/to/my/script.php"], shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")

# other things I tried
#with open("/tmp/value.txt", "r") as file:
#   stdout = file.readline() # output = "--"
#stdout = os.popen("cat /tmp/value.txt").read() # output = "--"
#stdout = subprocess.check_output(["php /path/to/my/script.php"], shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE).decode("utf-8") # output = "--"

print(str("-" + stdout + "-")) # output = "--"
```

php:

```
# php script
valueFile = fopen("/tmp/value.txt", "r");
value = trim(fgets($valueFile), "\n");
fclose($valueFile);
echo $value; # output in the shell is the value of $value
```

Edit: context: my python script is started by another python script, which listens for commands from an apache server on the pi. The value I want to read comes from a "1wire" device that listens for S0-signals.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us what you originally tried to read the file?

Comment: Does your script have permission to read from `/tmp`?

Comment: @drum yes it has. The extern script is creating other files in the /tmp directory as well which I am able to read.